# Embed media wiki in a frame

Tags: html, frame, wiki, mediawiki

Hi, I'm having difficulty using media wiki in a frame. I'm using the following code:

```
<frameset rows="25%,75%">
    <frame src="map.html"/>
    <frame src="wiki/index.php/Main_Page"/>
</frameset>
```

The problem I'm seeing is that there is no content in the wiki frame, even though if I navigate to that URL manually; it shows up.

**Edit:** Chrome is showing an error in the console: "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

Is there a configuration setting that I need to toggle?  Any ideas?

A common reaction people tend to have is **'don't use frames'** here's the end result I want:

In the other frame I have a map using GoogleMaps API V3 with a bunch of markers on the map.  I would like this to be the navigation of the wiki, so when the user clicks on a marker for i.e. Vancouver, the wiki auto-magically navigates to the Vancouver wiki entry.

Comment: Are you sure the wiki is located at that url? What does the DOM inspector say?

Comment: I'm only able to see the code as I've written it, I've tried using the absolute path with the same result.

Comment: Naa, I mean the DOM inspector applied on the frame. If it says about:blank, you'd know the path couldn't be resolved.

Comment: It all looks correct has the right path and all.  Chrome is showing an error, will edit it in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MediaWiki has a bunch of options regarding frames. Those two may cause your problem:

- [$wgEditPageFrameOptions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgEditPageFrameOptions)
- [$wgBreakFrames](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgBreakFrames)

In your MediaWiki 1.15, the `X-Frame-Options:DENY`-Header is hardcoded in [line 961 of OutputPage.php](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/branches/REL1_15/phase3/includes/OutputPage.php?view=markup#l961). If you know what you're doing, you might remove it.

Comment: I have been playing with both of these options, but I can't see any differences from my changes.  I'm making my changes in LocalSettings.php that is linked to from the mediawiki install directory (using vi).  Is that right?  Does it matter where in the file I add the lines?

Comment: Uh, I don't know exactly but it seems right. You may inspect the sent headers for a page in the networking tab of your favourite browsers console.

Comment: The frame's response is 200-OK, but I can see 'X-Frame-Options:DENY' in there, which is the problem I think

Comment: I just figured out that I have version 1.15.5-3build1 (the one Ubuntu packages) and $wgEditPageFrameOptions is for 1.16.1 and later.